# Removing the duplicate keys of a JSON array and getting its JSON path

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, key

I have the JSON below:

> {"response":{"result":{"Leads":{"row":[{"LEADID":"849730000000063017","SMOWNERID":"849730000000061001"},{"LEADID":"849730000000063015","SMOWNERID":"849730000000061001","HIII":"hello"},{"LEADID":"849730000000063007","SMOWNERID":"849730000000061001","BYEE":"tata"},{"LEADID":"849730000000063005","SMOWNERID":"849730000000061001"},{"LEADID":"849730000000063003","SMOWNERID":"849730000000061001"},{"LEADID":"849730000000063001","SMOWNERID":"849730000000061001"}]}},"uri":"/crm/private/json/Leads/getMyRecords"}}

I have the requirement to get the JSON path, for which I used the code below:

```
var str={"response":{"result":{"Leads":{"row":[{"LEADID":"849730000000063017","SMOWNERID":"849730000000061001",},
  {"LEADID":"849730000000063015","SMOWNERID":"849730000000061001"},
  {"LEADID":"849730000000063007","SMOWNERID":"849730000000061001","HIII":"hello"},
  {"LEADID":"849730000000063005","SMOWNERID":"849730000000061001","BYEE":"tata"},
  {"LEADID":"849730000000063003","SMOWNERID":"849730000000061001"},
  {"LEADID":"849730000000063001","SMOWNERID":"849730000000061001"}]}},
  "uri":"/crm/private/json/Leads/getMyRecords"}}
var keys = [];
getKeys(keys,str, '');
for(var i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
  var d=new Array();
  d=keys[i][1].replace(/^\.|\.$/g, '')
  console.log(keys[i][0] + '=' +d)
}
function getKeys(keys, obj, path) {
  for(key in obj) {
    var currpath = path+'.'+key;
    keys.push([key, currpath]);
    if(typeof(obj[key]) === 'object') {
      getKeys(keys, obj[key], currpath);
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the output:

```
response=response
result=response.result
Leads=response.result.Leads
row=response.result.Leads.row
0=response.result.Leads.row.0
LEADID=response.result.Leads.row.0.LEADID
SMOWNERID=response.result.Leads.row.0.SMOWNERID
1=response.result.Leads.row.1
LEADID=response.result.Leads.row.1.LEADID
SMOWNERID=response.result.Leads.row.1.SMOWNERID
HIII=response.result.Leads.row.1.HIII
2=response.result.Leads.row.2
LEADID=response.result.Leads.row.2.LEADID
SMOWNERID=response.result.Leads.row.2.SMOWNERID
 BYEE=response.result.Leads.row.2.BYEE
3=response.result.Leads.row.3
LEADID=response.result.Leads.row.3.LEADID
SMOWNERID=response.result.Leads.row.3.SMOWNERID
4=response.result.Leads.row.4
LEADID=response.result.Leads.row.4.LEADID
SMOWNERID=response.result.Leads.row.4.SMOWNERID
5=response.result.Leads.row.5
LEADID=response.result.Leads.row.5.LEADID
SMOWNERID=response.result.Leads.row.5.SMOWNERID
uri=response.uri
```

The array elements keys are repetitive (ie) LEADID and SMOWNERID are repetitive in the array. I want to remove the duplicates of the entire array and display the output like this:

```
response=response
result=response.result
Leads=response.result.Leads
row=response.result.Leads.row
0=response.result.Leads.row.0
LEADID=response.result.Leads.row.0.LEADID
SMOWNERID=response.result.Leads.row.0.SMOWNERID
HIII=response.result.Leads.row.0.HIII
BYEE=response.result.Leads.row.0.BYEE
uri=response.uri
```

I am stuck here, any help regarding this will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the function `getKeys` to this :

```
function getKeys(keys, obj, path) {
  for(key in obj) {
    var currpath = path+'.'+key;
    keys.push([key, currpath]);
    if(typeof(obj[key]) === 'object') {
      if(obj[key] instanceof Array){                   //added check for array
        keys.push(['0', currpath+'.0']);
        getKeys(keys, obj[key][0], currpath+'.0');
      }
      else
      getKeys(keys, obj[key], currpath);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Update

```
function getKeys(keys, obj, path) {
  for(key in obj) {
    var currpath = path+'.'+key;
    addKeys(key, currpath);
    //keys.push([key, currpath]);
    if(typeof(obj[key]) === 'object') {
      getKeys(keys, obj[key], currpath);
    }
  }
}

function addKeys(key, currpath) {                      //check before adding
  present = keys.map(function(x){return(x[1].split('.').slice(-1)[0])});
  if (present.indexOf(key)==-1){
    keys.push([key, currpath]);
  }
}
```

The answer is not exactly like you want but is the closest I could get. Also the values you have given for HIII and BYEE are wrong. Lastly it is possible to have same keys at different levels, but I am only matching the name of key. It may not work if same keyname is used at different levels.

Comment: :This code works but it prints only the value from the first instance of the array.what if i have different keys in the second and third instance and I just want to prevent duplication in the array.This is a gud starting point.If u have any idea on the above query please do suggest a solution

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to change the keys to object from array - change the `var keys = []` to `var keys = {}` and then change the getKeys method as follow:

```
function getKeys(keys, obj, path) {
 for(key in obj) {
  var currpath = path+'.'+key;
  if(keys[key])
    continue;
  keys[key] = currpath;
  if(typeof(obj[key]) === 'object') {
    getKeys(keys, obj[key], currpath);
  }
 }
}
```

Now you will also need to change the way you print the values after the return from getKeys since now keys is not an array rather an object.